# Spring 4 Rest Controller throwing JsonMappingException

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I Have one property in my Java class with return type as `Map<String,List<Object>` while parsing it using Jackson I am getting below exception. Can anyone please help me on this?

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write content: Class java.lang.String not subtype of
>   [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class
>   java.lang.Object]] (through reference chain: 
>   com.test.model["dropdownModel"]); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class
>   java.lang.String not subtype of [collection type; class
>   java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]
>   (through reference chain: com.test.model["dropdownModel"])

This is what the bean I am trying to parse using Jackson:

```
public class AdminModel {
    private Map<String, List<LabelValueModel>> dropdownModel = null;
    public Map<String, List<LabelValueModel>> getDropdownModel() {
        return dropdownModel;
    }
    public void setDropdownModel( Map<String, List<LabelValueModel>> dropdownModel ) {
        this.dropdownModel = dropdownModel;
    }
}
```

This is my rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDropdownValues", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Accept=application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<AdminModel> getDropdownValues( @RequestBody DropDownModel inModel ) {
    AdminModel responseModel = adminService.getDropdownValues( inModel ); 
    return new ResponseEntity<AdminModel>( responseModel, HttpStatus.OK );
}
```

Comment: Can somebody plz respond quick?

Comment: Please comment the curl request you are posing

Comment: Checks that your map contains only instance of `List<LabelValueModel>`

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by the fact that my map was a `Map<String, List<String>>` and I had put `("key", "value")`, which, of course, is illegal. It was allowing it because at one point it was a `Map<String, Object>` so it was fine.

Changing this to put a list fixed my issue.